# How to get CSRF token from mobile apps when CSRF_USE_SESSIONS is True ? (Django 1.11)

Tags: android, json, django, session-cookies, csrf

Good evening everybody,

As a student group, we are developing an API using Django 1.11.2 and we would like to consume our API from mobile apps (such as Android applications).

Currently, we are struggling getting the CSRF token from mobile applications, here's the background :

- We are using CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True. From what I understand from the [Django CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/), the token is stored in the session instead of a cookie.
- We are using the SessionMiddleware in which the SESSION_ENGINE is configured as `'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'`
- For the big authentication part, we are using class-based views.
- In multiple templates, we are using `{% csrf_token %}` into forms in order to protect them during POST requests.

Everything works great when consuming the API from a non-mobile web client. However, when consuming it from an Android application, we face multiple problems. What we tried so far was - during a GET request - getting the CSRF token from the session and sending it through `Accept: 'application/json'` :

```
class Login(LoginView):

form_class = AuthenticationForm
template_name = 'users/login.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT') == 'application/json':
        csrftoken = request.session.get(CSRF_SESSION_KEY)
        return JsonResponse({
            'csrf-header-name': 'X-CSRFToken',
            'csrf-token': csrftoken
        }, status=200)
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT') == 'application/json':
        form = self.get_form()
        if not form.is_valid():
            print(form.errors.as_text())
            return JsonResponse({'error': form.errors.as_text()}, status=400)
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that we can't get the session from `'application/json'`, it seems that the session cookie isn't sent (but it does work well when not using `'application/json'`). Thus, the `'csrf-token'` in the JSONResponse simply returns a null value.

Have you ever faced this case ? Do you have any recommendations to get the CSRF token when storing it in sessions ?

Comment: Note that `get_form()` uses `request.POST` which expects the form data to be form encoded. If you are json encoding the data, you'll have to decode it and pass it to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the [`get_token`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py#L74) method.

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

csrftoken = get_token(request)
```

Comment: Alasdair Does `get_token` make sure that the token comes from the session ?

Comment: When you're in the view, I don't think you need to worry about whether you are storing the token in a cookie or in the session. The CSRF middleware will take care of that for you.

Comment: Okay, I have a last question though - since I don't quite understand and I'm still learning : what would be a clean way to get the token from a mobile application ? I thought about creating a specific URL (like /get-token/) that would return a CSRF and then use it in any POST request. What do you think about this ?

Comment: That sounds like it would work to me. However I'm not an expert in this area so don't know what the best practice is.

Comment: is that you find solution because i am also facing same problem